# Nero installation error

Tags: windows-vista, installation, nero

I have vista. I was trying to install nero 9. But the setup failed in between. But the temporary files that the setup extracted are still there on my system. They are taking space of around 1 GB.( I saw disk usage before and after the installation). **How to remove those files?**(means what is the location) I have already deleted the folder "Nero" it created inside Program Files. But I am sure that temoporary files are still there. Also how to remove the entry from installed programs in Control Panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the official **[Nero General Clean Tool](http://www.nero.com/eng/tools-utilities.html)**:

> **Uninstalling a Nero product did not work correctly?**
>
> Use Nero General CleanTool to delete
>   all remaining Nero entries from your
>   system.
>
> **Please proceed as follows:**
>
> Download the Nero General CleanTool,
>   save this file to your desktop. Unzip
>   the ZIP-file with WinZip or WinRAR and
>   save the content to your hard drive.
>   Double-click on the unzipped EXE-file
>   to start the CleanTool. The window
>   “Nero General CleanTool” will open.
>   The Nero products installed will be
>   displayed.
>
> Check the boxes next to the Nero
>   products you want to remove. Then
>   click the “Clean” button. A status
>   window will open. The execution of the
>   tool may take several minutes.
>
> Please wait until the progress bar has
>   moved completely to the right. In the
>   window “Nero General CleanTool” click
>   the “Exit” button as soon as the
>   erasing procedure is completed.
>
> Reboot your computer. The Nero General
>   CleanTool has removed all selected
>   Nero entries from your computer.

Comment: Sure! trust the guys who messed your system up in the first place to clean it! :P

Comment: who knows better then them how to clean up any possible mess?

Answer (score 2):

[CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) and [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) should take care of all of that.